# How to have the message text showed up in my command line?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I use pytelegrambotapi library to make my bot in telegram.

Here is my code:

```
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello. I'm your bot")
    print(message.text)
```

What I want to do is to return the message text in my command line. It returns nothing, however, the bot is working since it answers me in telegram.

Comment: Have you tried python `logging` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, the code is running in separate Tread/Process, which does not have access to the console, and hence, not able to print something in it.

Use logging to file instead of print.

Here is a useful link - https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot#logging

Comment: thx, but actually i used print only to indicate the fact that messages received by bot can affect some local variables for example. Like: if message.text == "hello": local_var =1

Answer (score 0):

This one works but it will simply spit out the entire content.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    print(message)
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
```

I am trying to find a better alternative hope I will make this process simple.

```
##updated
print(message.text)
```

I have tested it.